# Add image sprite to svg using D3 and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Trying to add image sprites to svg using css  background and background-position as instructions from http://www.flag-sprites.com The img placeholders show up in the debug tools in the right position but is blank. It seems the css is not setting the background for some reason. I have a flag sprite showing on the same page with basic html so it seems to be a problem only with svg.  The CSS looks like this.

```
    .flag {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: url('../images/flags.png') no-repeat;

}


.flag.flag-mm {
    background-position: -352px -256px;
}

.flag.flag-bf {
    background-position: -128px -32px;
}
```

javaScript

```
const node = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("image")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("image")
        //.append("img")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return `flag flag-${d.code}`})
        .attr("xlink:href", "/dist/images/blank.gif")
```

Comment: What is `"xlink:src"`?

Comment: that should be xlink:href forgot to chang it back after trying some things. will edit above

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find an answer to my original question but found a work around. I added a div with class for flags to the graph container

```
<div id="graph">      
  <div class="flag-holder"></div>
</div>
```

then added an img per node via the graph selection

```
  var node = graph.select(".flag-holder").selectAll(".node")
        .data(json.nodes)
        .enter().append("img")
        .attr('class', d => 'flag flag-' + d.code)
```

and finally on each tick of the d3 graph added the style left and top

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
    return d.source.x;
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return d.source.y;
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return d.target.x;
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return d.target.y;
  });
  node.style('left', d => (d.x - 8) + "px")
      .style('top', d => (d.y - 5) + "px");
});
```